# FileReference.upload() doesn't upload locally

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, security, iis-7

Trying to upload using flash swf on my local machine running Windows with IIS and PHP 5.3 installed.

```
var selected_file:FileReference = GetSelectedFile();
var url:String = 'http://localhost.com/upload.php';
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
req.data = new URLVariables('source=' + 'computer');
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
selected_file.upload(req, 'file', false);

selected_file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, UploadComplete, false, 0, true);
selected_file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, UploadProgress, false, 0, true);
selected_file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, UploadError, false, 0, true);
selected_file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, UploadSecurityError, false, 0, true);
```

I've set breakpoints on all the handler functions. I hit a breakpoint on `UploadProgress` handler. However, the file isn't being uploaded. When looking at network traffic there is no call to `upload.php`.

Looking at [documentation for FileReference upload](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html) function I see this:

> Uploads and downloads are not allowed if the calling SWF file is in
>   the local-with-filesystem sandbox

Looking at definition of [local-with-filesystem sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c8f) I found this:

> From this sandbox, executable code can read local files (by using the
>   URLLoader class, for example), but cannot communicate with the network
>   in any way. This assures the user that local data cannot be leaked out
>   to the network or otherwise inappropriately shared.

Does this mean there isn't a way to test uploads on local machine?

**update:**  Supposedly I need to have [Security.sandboxType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c52) as `LOCAL_TRUSTED`. I've been trying to set security type by adding configuration file [for user](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c91.html#WSD2DCB535-92C6-49ff-8954-D8D5130404F1) and [globally](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c95.html#WS357943C4-11D4-4b2a-ADAD-3B485BF39CBF).  Configuration file has `cfg` extension and contains one line, path to folder where my swf file resides.

Still after adding this configuration, Security.sandboxType is set to "remote".

Comment: Did you try setting the Global Flash Player Trust directory? "There is also a Global Flash Player Trust directory, used by the administrative user or installers to register an application for all users of a computer (see Administrator controls)."

Comment: Also, check your Security Settings in your Settings Manager (http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html)

Comment: Added folder path to my swf file to Flash Settings Manager -> Advanced -> Trusted Locations.   Added a text file to `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust` that contains a path to my swf.  Still have same behavior. `Security.sandboxType` is still set to "remote".

Comment: Where is swf file hosted?

Comment: SWF is on my local pc. I basically have my development environment running on my local machine, Windows 7 using IIS. I have IIS web server that loads html page that loads swf using swfobject js library.

Comment: Output errors in upload.php. You say it's not being hit, but I'm suspicious. Can you also make sure you set the permissions of the destination "upload" folder?

Comment: is localhost.com correct? (.com?)

Comment: yes. i configured my host file to accept localhost.com. this was done for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you accessing the SWF file at `file://.../main.swf` or `http://localhost.com/.../main.swf` - I believe that determines whether you're in the local or remote sandbox.  You probably want the latter for easiest communication with your hosted PHP file.  If they're on the same server, then you don't need any special security settings.  You may also be able to access the selected_file.data ByteArray (after it is uploaded) and send it to your sever as shown by my other answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854952/8856655#8856655

Answer (score 0):

[According to Adobe:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html)

> The local-with-filesystem sandbox—For security purposes, Flash Player places all local SWF files and assets in the local-with-file-system sandbox, by default. From this sandbox, **SWF files can read local files** (by using the URLLoader class, for example), **but they cannot communicate with the network in any way**. This assures the user that local data cannot be leaked out to the network or otherwise inappropriately shared.

You cannot access the file system **and** network within one SWF instance in normal situations.

However, it appears to be possible to grant this ability to a specific SWF by adding the file to the local trusted sandbox. [According to Senocular, this may be accomplished in three different ways...](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/Flash%20Player%20Security%20Basics.html)

> - SWFs run within Flex Builder 2 or the Flash Authoring environment
> - SWFs located in a directory the user has granted permissions for from    the (online only) Global Security Settings Panel.
> - SWFs located in a directory specified in a Flash Player trust    configuration (.cfg) file on the local system

**For the Configuration File Option:**

1. You need to compile your SWF with the `local playback setting` selected.
2. This means you need to place your configuration file in
   `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust\` 
   *If the folder doesn't exist you must create it.*
3. Then create your configuration file *(naming it whatever you
   please.cfg*) Finally, type `C:\` into the file and save it.
4. Now your whole C:\ directory should be declared local_trusted and shouldn't have any issues contacting your server and accessing your files.