# Actionscript - Loading a file freezes application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to upload a file from user's computer to our server. From what I understand I need to load this file first using [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) and then I can send the bytes loaded to our server.

I'm loading a file using [FileReference.load](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load%28%29)  method. When a file is large ~3MB the application freezes until load is complete.

Note: I'm not using AIR this is a swf that is uploaded to web.

Comment: What kind of file are you loading? And what will you be doing with it once loaded... just to get an idea of your requirements.

Comment: I would say use URLLoader to load the file and FileReference to save it. But again, I need to understand your requirements. Can you Post some codes?

Comment: Updated my question with more detail. I'm not restricting file type, it can be an image or a pdf.  Once it is loaded I'm saving it to our server. I'm picking this file from computer, so does URLLoader apply in this scenario? It looks like URLLoader used for downloading http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: Yes URLLoader is for downloading data, I'm not sure if you can use it to download a file from the users computer. If it is possible you would probably need to get the FileReference and then somehow pass the  URLRequest to the URLLoader. Then you would use URLRequest to upload to the server. However, try what @Fygo suggested...

Comment: Perhaps offload the offending code to a worker thread? If the app freezes, maybe because of posting HTTP request, making another asynchronous-by-default layer can help. Or are there issues with security, workers and accessing `FileReference`?

Comment: As you are using filerefernce to upload so it must uploading in a popup you can try by removing the popup. So it will run in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileStream class to load the file asynchronously.

Check this [link](http://snipplr.com/view/2937/).

I have copied the code here for you, in case the link expires this would help you.

```
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
      import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
      import flash.filesystem.File;
      import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
      import flash.events.Event;

      // Declare the FileStream and String variables

      private var _fileStream:FileStream;

      private var _fileContents:String;

      private function onCreationComplete():void // Fired when the application has been created

      {

      var myFile:File = File.appResourceDirectory; // Create out file object and tell our File Object where to look for the file

      myFile = myFile.resolve("mySampleFile.txt"); // Point it to an actual file


      _fileStream = new FileStream(); // Create our file stream

      _fileStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onFileProgress); // Add our the progress event listener

      _fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileComplete); // Add our the complete event listener

      _fileStream.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.READ); // Call the openAsync() method instead of open()

      }
      private function onFileProgress(p_evt:ProgressEvent):void // Event handler for the PROGRESS Event
      {
      _fileContents += _fileStream.readMultiByte(_fileStream.bytesAvailable, "iso-8859-1"); // Read the contens of the file and add to the contents variable

      fileContents_txt.text = _fileContents; // Display the contents. I've created a TextArea on the stage for display
      }

      private function onFileComplete(p_evt:Event):void // Event handler for the COMPLETE event

      {
      _fileStream.close(); // Clean up and close the file stream
      }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately `FileStream` is available only for Adobe AIR applications.

Comment: @Subash Selvaraj, you might want to consider removing this answer before you get downvoted.
dev.e.loper can you update your question to specify Flash Player as it can be confused for Air applications which are increasingly common these days (as opposed to Flash Player apps anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you should load the file with FileReference.load(). Is there any particular reason for it? If you load the file, it will just (uselessly) occupy the memory. Are you making anything at all with that file in your application or you just want to upload it as it is?

In case of pure upload there is a much better method for it: FileReference.upload() ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload%28%29 ). It will upload the file without loading it into Flash Player. The flow is the same, you need to trigger the .browse(), listen to select event and then call the upload().

EDIT: Btw, I am not quite sure why your app freezes. That should not happen with .load() either - it is asynchronous. Plus a 3MB file will load lightning fast. Or at least it should. What are you doing with the file after it completes the load, doesn't that freeze your app?

Comment: `upload` method was the first thing I tried. However I ran into security roadblock. I spent considerable time trying to figuring it out before giving up. Now I do `load` file first and then use a http post to upload loaded file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185329/filereference-upload-doesnt-upload-locally

Comment: Well, it is really difficult to help you out without any code sample. If I was you I would try to resolve the security issue or actually set up my files on a server (just the server-side ones), you can test the swf from localhost. You won't be able to use URLLoader - the user cannot select files thru it + there is the sandbox. You can use only FileReference. If you are sure the user won't load large files load() could work but as you said the app freezes - can you provide more details?